# Increasing the heap size for eclipse application to run

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We have some file which is of size 200mb.So it was taking around 15 minutes to import and load the files. So I increased my heap size to 1Gb and checked it it took around 8 minutes.So now if I try to increase the heap size to 2Gb We are getting error as:

```
Cannot connect to VM
Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2560000KB object heap
```

In VM Arguments I configured as:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-Xss8m
```

System Requirement is:8Gb Ram,i5 processor

Comment: If the operating system on VM has an architecture of 32b you will not be able to increase the RAM dimensions over 2Gb

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 32 bit JVM on a 32 bit OS you will struggle to get much more than `-Xmx1024m` (you may be able to increase it to something like `-Xmx1400m` but not `-Xmx2048m`)

For more memory than this you will need a 64 bit JVM on a 64 bit OS.